# How do I install the Rake Jenkins plugin?

Tags: plugins, installation, rake, jenkins

I'm puzzled how I install the rake plugin; and where to find a release version.

I require this to run my rake build script on a Win2008 server. This builds asp.net websites.

Will I need to build the source myself using the JDK? Where will the .hpi file be?

Answer (score 2):

The [Rake Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rake+plugin) for Jenkins is available to install in the same way as all other plugins — via the [Plugin Manager](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Howtoinstallplugins).

This plugin requires Jenkins 1.398 or newer; if you have 1.442 or newer, you can also install new plugins without having to restart Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what to do under ideal circumstances. The final problem is that my dev build server is not directly connected to the internet, so I get an error telling me to configure a proxy server. There is a proxy configured but not for the necessary sites.[p]

Is it possible to directly download the plugin - in a similar manner  to how one downloads a ruby gem (when there's no direct connection)?

Comment: **Yo:** https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins tells us where the hpi files are hiding.